# elements sorting and grouping within a list in python

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x

I get different lists from a random list generator and I have to check which of these lists would be accepted, the condition : the elements of the same type are grouped together ,other elements are not concerned. For example : 
L1 = [Device1,Device2,Device3,Device4,Device5,Device6,Device7,Device8] 
every device has a type: 
TypeL1 =[H,U,U,K,D,P,F,D]
a correct config would be: [x,U,U,x,D,D,x,x]
in my code I tried to find the repeated elements indexes and then I sorted them and saved in an another list. But it doesn't help me too much. for the above example I got L=[U,U,D,D].I'm stuck and I'm in luck of ideas.Im a beginner in Programming so any help will be great.

### the code

```
D=[i for i ,x in enumerate (check_type)if check_type.count(x)> 1]
logging.info("the index repeted elem : %s",D)
X = len(D)
print ("length D:",X)
Flag.clear()
while len(D)>1:
    A=check_type[int(D[0])]
    print("A:",A)
    for i in range(0,len(D)):
        if check_type[int(D[i])] == A:
            Flag.append(D[i])
    print ("Flag:",Flag )

    D=list(set(D).difference(Flag))
    print ("D:",D)
logging.info("the sorted indexes:%s",Flag)
```

Comment: are you aware there is an actual function in python called [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) it would likely be helpful to you.

Comment: Your paragraph has reference to ( I think) variables like `L1` and `TypeL1` but they are not represented in your code, could you maybe keep the variable names consistent?

Answer (score 0):

```
L = ['H', 'U', 'P', 'P', 'K', 'H', 'U', 'H', 'D', 'P'] # List of devices
T = {'H','U','K','D','P','F','F'} # List of types
res = []
for t in T:
v = [l for l in L if l == t]
for i in v: res.append(i)
print(res)
```

Ouput :

```
['D', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'K', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'U', 'U']
```

My approch using python3.x
- For each type of devices I grouped devices using list comprehension in v.Finaly a add v elements to another the return list.

Comment: interesting... you use both list comprehension and `for i in v: res.append(i)` which is exactly the case where you should use list comprehension... may I ask: why?

Comment: Also please add at least a little bit of explanation to your code, I'm not sure if this would solve the problem or not but it would be much easier to tell if you added an explanation!

Comment: Thanks for your remarks.I added a brief explanation, hope it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I find an another way : I used a list of lists and in each element I saved the matched item. Then I converted the list of lists in one list and removed the repeated elements. I got the result I want.

```
lista= []
    for i in range (0,len(check_type)):
        lista.append([])
        #print(lista)
        for j in range(0,len(check_type)):   
            if check_type[i]==check_type[j]:
               lista[i].append(j)
    #print ('The List of lists!! :',lista) 
    A = (list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lista)))
    #print ('The converted list indexes!! :',A)
    B=[k for n ,k in enumerate(A) if k not in A[:n]]
    logging.info ('The final correct list indexes!! :%s',B)
```